# Compass modifies but doesn't change css

Tags: css, sass, compass

When I run command `compass watch` and edit some scss file, I get only console massage: `modified scss/base.scss`, but don't get message about changes in css files. The css files don't change.

When I remove all files from css folder manually and run `compass watch`, I get `write css/base.css`.

Why compass doesn't update css files after updating my scss?

config.rb:

```
require 'compass/import-once/activate'

http_path = "/"
css_dir = "css"
sass_dir = "scss"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "javascripts"
```

Comment: With the info you have given, it doesn't sound like your setup is quite right. You might benefit from an app like Scout which handles Compass compiling much easier: http://mhs.github.io/scout-app/

Comment: show us your config.rb

Comment: @austinthedeveloper, I'v used this installation about a half of year. But get this situetion at first time.

Comment: @mfreitas, I have added my config.rb

Comment: Random thought: Does this happen when you edit any of your .scss files in /scss or just one? Maybe the one file that is having issues wasn't included in your main style.scss. This is assuming that you have multiple SCSS files.

Comment: @austinthedeveloper, I have one file base.scss included some scss with '_filename.scss'. This problem heppens with all files even whith base.scss

Answer (score 0):

it's kind of late now
I encountered the same issue recently and found the issue is that
you need to import bass.scss in module.scss (I use sass, so it's module.sass in my case).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else happening upon this - as the OP mentioned, their setup was already working for several months before this crept up. The same was the case for me. I simply needed to close terminal and reopen it (cancelling and restarting compass watch was not enough).